# jqGrid view wrong record with multiselect

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm developing a grid using jqGrid to handle a set of records.
In this grid the user can view a record's details where it shows aditional information and multiselect is set to true to process several records at once on the backend.

However there is a problem viewing records details where the wrong record is displayed.

Steps to reproduce the error:

1. select record
2. view selected row (on navigation bar)
3. close dialog
4. select a different record
5. view selected row (on navigation bar)

On step 5 the record shown is the record select on step 1.

You can reproduce the error using this link:

http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action

Here is the code I'm using to create the grid

```
<sjg:grid id="rtvReplicationJobsGrid"
                autowidth="true" 
                gridview="true"
                indicator="true"
                dataType="json"
                onCompleteTopics="onCompleteGrid"
                href="%{remoteurl}"
                pager="true"
                gridModel="data"
                rowList="10,15,20,50"
                rowNum="15"
                rownumbers="false"
                editinline="false"
                navigator="true"
                navigatorAdd="false"
                navigatorEdit="false"
                navigatorDelete="false"
                navigatorView="true"
                navigatorSearchOptions="{multipleSearch:true}"
                multiselect="true"
                multiboxonly="true"
                navigatorExtraButtons="{
                    'delete' : {  id: 'deleteButton',
                        icon: 'ui-icon-trash',  
                        title: 'Delete Jobs',
                        onclick: deleteJobsDialogFunction
                    },
                    seperator: {
                        title : 'seperator'  
                    },
                    replicated : {
                        id : 'replicatedButton',
                        title : 'Mark as Replicated', 
                        caption : 'Replicated', 
                        icon: 'ui-icon-check',
                        onclick: markAsReplicatedDialogFunction
                    },
                    replicate : {
                        id : 'replicateButton',
                        title : 'Mark for Replication', 
                        caption : 'Replicate', 
                        icon: 'ui-icon-play', 
                        onclick: startReplicationDialogFunction
                    }}">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not struts2 developer. Thus I can't gives you exact instructions how you can fix the problem in struts2. Nevertheless I will gives you some tips which I hope will allows you to fix the problem.

First of all it seems to me that you use jqGrid 4.6. It has the bug which I described [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/edit-and-add-not-working-simultaneously#p31070) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/edit-form-ok-at-first-call-then-always-display-same-values#p31373) together with the corresponding workaround.

You can solve the problem in many ways. The first one: you can replace old jqGrid 4.6 with new [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.9.2. To do this you can replace the file `ui.jqgrid.css` from `/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/struts/themes/ui.jqgrid.css` to the new version from free jqGrid, copy/replace `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`, `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` and `jquery.jqgrid.min.map` in the folder `/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/struts/js/plugins/` and replace `grid.filter.js` and `grid.formedit.js` from `/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/struts/js/plugins/` with **empty** files with the same names. Finally yu should replace `grid.locale-en.js` from `/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/struts/i18n/` to the corresponding frome from free jqGrid. In the way you will full replace jqGrid 4.6 used by struts2 to free jqGrid which has vary good upwards compatibility with jqGrid 4.6. It should fix the described problem.

Alternatively you can hold usage of old jqGrid 4.6, but to add `navigatorViewOptions` and `navigatorEditOptions` which specify `beforeInitData` which removes previously created View or Edit/Add form. The corresponding code could be something like

```
navigatorViewOptions="{
                recreateForm: true,
                beforeInitData: function () {
                    $('#viewmod' + this.id).remove();
                }
            }"
```

and

```
navigatorViewOptions="{
                recreateForm: true,
                beforeInitData: function () {
                    $('#editmod' + this.id).remove();
                }
            }"
```

One more alternative would be the usage of the following JavaScript code

```
$.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
$.jgrid.edit = $.jgrid.edit || {};
$.jgrid.view = $.jgrid.view || {};
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.view, {
    recreateForm: true,
    beforeInitData: function () {
        $("#viewmod" + this.id).remove();
    }
});
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.edit, {
    recreateForm: true,
    beforeInitData: function () {
        $("#editmod" + this.id).remove();
    }
});
```

which defines default implementation of `beforeInitData`.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that will do the trick. I started working on a different project. As soon as I have time I'll try your instructions. Thanks.

Comment: @Raimundo: You are welcome! I wrote you at the beginning that I don't use  struts2 myself. I just tried to wrote you some possible ways to solve the problem (if I understand it correctly). It would be good if you will write shortly for other struts2 developers which way you have chosen and whether the way really worked.

Comment: I went for alternative number 2. Although I think the update alternative is the best one, I don't have the permission to go for that.
Thanks.

Comment: @Raimundo: You are welcome! Thanks for the information.